# nodejs error connecting to AWS RDS postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to my postgresql DB I am using the [pg](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool) library, my code looks like this

```
const dbcreds = require("./dbconfig.json")
const { Pool } = require('pg')

pushToDB =  async function (shiftData) {
    const pool = await new Pool({
        host: dbcreds.dbhost,
        user: dbcreds.user, 
        password: dbcreds.dbpassword,
        database: dbcreds.dbname,
    })

    await pool.connect()
    await pool.query('INSERT into working (shift_id, client_id, organisational_unit, discipline, site, starts_at, ends_at, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3) returning id', ['shift id', 'client id', 'third'], function (err, result) {
        done();
        if (err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        res.send(result);
    });
}
```

Checking the logs on AWS shows me this after running my code, I think this may be due to AWS permission errors but I'm not sure exactly what I need to change:

```
2019-06-26 09:09:46 UTC:46-247-17-105.fluidata.co.uk(50780):robert@sstreamdb:[9627]:FATAL: password authentication failed for user "robert"
2019-06-26 09:09:46 UTC:46-247-17-105.fluidata.co.uk(50780):robert@sstreamdb:[9627]:DETAIL: Role "robert" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 13: "host   all all 0.0.0.0/0   md5"
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDS database username and password is not your AWS user name and password, they are different identities.

In this case, the error message is pretty clear : `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "robert"`

So either, the Postgres RDS username or password is incorrect.  Check with the owner of the RDS database what correct credentials are.  If you created the RDS database, be sure to create a `Robert` user at Postgres level.  You can refer to this blog for more details https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/ .

Finally, when you will get this working, we strongly discourage embedding database credentials in your application.  I would suggest you to use AWS Secret Manager instead and rewrite your code to fetch the secret at runtime.  You will find an example here : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/rotate-amazon-rds-database-credentials-automatically-with-aws-secrets-manager/

Comment: I have connected to my db using psql and then used `create user robert` and `grant all privileges on database sstreamdb to robert` but I still get the same error

Comment: what password did youa ssign to user 'robert' ?  Also, if you connected to the DB to create user robert, it means you *do* have a username/password to connect to it.  What if you (temporarly) try to use these crednetials from your code ?  Does that work ?

Comment: to connect to my db I used  `psql "host=dbcreds.dbhost port=5432 dbname=dbcreds.dbname user=dbcreds.user"` Once connected I created the user `robert` with no password

Comment: if your user has no password and you're passing a password to the connection `password: dbcreds.dbpassword,` you will have problems.  Try to add a password to the user (no password option is not secure) and use the same password from your code.

Comment: I've done that and still get the error how would I specify the user i loin with